# Is this a valid way of calculating the "average amount per timespan"?

Tags: c#, algorithm, statistics

Let's assume I have a list of "events" consisting of events that happened with both their Timestamp and their amount recorded. I would like to calculate the "average amount / minute" based on this list. Is my current implementation missing something important or do I have a valid implementation?

Note: It does not have to be 100.0% accurate. I understand that this is a very simple way of finding the data I am looking for and I am okay with "not the best precision".

```
struct SomeEvent
{
    public DateTime Time;
    public uint Amount;
}

private static var lastEvents = new List<SomeEvent>();

double GetRatePerMinute()
{
    if(lastEvents.Count == 0)
        return 0.0;

    // Time since the first event was recorded, in minutes.
    double timespan = (DateTime.Now - lastEvents[0].Time).TotalMinutes;

    // Add up the total amount
    uint totalAmount = 0;
    foreach(var e in lastEvents)
    {
        totalAmount += e.Amount;
    }

    // Amount / Time?
    return (totalAmount / timespan);
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use Sum(event end - event start)/ total time.  Your method will always give a number very close to 1.  You are just using the event start time.

Comment: @jdweng No, I am calculating the timespan between now and when the very first event happen (this first event in the list). Maybe you misread that line? It seems to work "okay" in my tests. :)

Comment: How do you tell when an event finished?

Comment: Maybe I described that wrong. The calculation is based on when it happened (there is no start or end, just "happened"). Example: A customer bought a banana for 2$. I just record the 2$ and the time that it "happened". But I don't store the beginning (customer entered the shop) or end (customer left the shop).

Comment: Then don't you just want (number of times or amount)/timespan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you miss something, but you could simplify GetRatePerMinute as follows:

```
static double GetRatePerMinute()
{
    return lastEvents.Count == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)lastEvents.Sum(x => x.Amount) / (DateTime.Now - lastEvents[0].Time).TotalMinutes;
}
```

And if you don't want to assume that the first element in lastEvents holds the first time stamp, you could use:

```
static double GetRatePerMinute_safe()
{
    return lastEvents.Count == 0 ? 0.0 : (double)lastEvents.Sum(x => x.Amount) / (DateTime.Now - lastEvents.Select(e => e.Time).Min()).TotalMinutes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The last one was a nice simplification!